# Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found - Error with IF-ELSE condition - FreePascal

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I dont understand why my code doesn't compile, can anyone help me about this.
Any kind of comment is helpful

this is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  days : integer;
begin
  if(Edit2.Text <> '') then
    days:= StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    DDate.Minus(days);
    Edit1.Text := DDate.GetDate
  else
    ShowMessage('The field is required');
end;
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?  that would be helpful to include in the post.

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of `Edit1.Text := ...`......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two or more statements for true_statement or false_statement, then the group of statements must be placed within a begin ... end Block

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  days: integer;
begin
  if(Edit2.Text <> '') then
   begin
    days := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    DDate.Resta(days);
    Edit1.Text := DDate.GetDate;
   end
  else
    ShowMessage('The field is required');
end;
```

Source: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Else

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the part after if be enclosed in begin-end block? The indentation suggests so. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  days : integer;
begin
  if(Edit2.Text <> '') then
    begin
      days:= StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
      DDate.Minus(days);
      Edit1.Text := DDate.GetDate;
    end
  else
    ShowMessage('The field is required');
end;
```